# Touchpad unresponsive on resume from sleep on Debian 8

Tags: debian, sleep, freeze, touchpad

I installed Debian a few weeks ago on my laptop.

When I close the lid and re open it, my touchpad does not respond. If I connect a usb mouse it works great but the touchpad does not. I tried to create `/etc/pm/sleep.d/00_trackpad`:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
suspend|hibernate)
modprobe -r psmouse ;;
resume|thaw)
modprobe psmouse ;;
synclient TouchpadOff=0 ;;
esac
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
resume)
DISPLAY=:0.0 su USER -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0' ;;
esac
```

But neither works.

Computer : Asus 455L

OS :Debian GNU/Linux 8(Jessie) 64 bit. Gnome v 3014.1

Comment: I wouldn't downvote this, it's not a bad question. It's just the wrong place to ask.

Comment: I know, but i tried several place and no one seems  want/can answer me. I just thought stackoverflow had a bigger community so more chance to have an answer. I'm pretty desperate, i can't find the solution to my problem. Should i remove the post ?

Comment: You can ask most Debian questions on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). (Ubuntu is just a Debian fork.) When you search for the word `suspend` instead of `hibernate` you may also find some answers. [ex 1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/671910/touchpad-not-working-after-suspending-laptop) [ex 2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194810)

Comment: I added some new possible solutions, see it any of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Weird things can happen when you close and open your lid on a laptop that did not have Debian originally installed. I've seen a bunch of those.

It is not Debian's fault -- some of those laptops have a hardware switch for the screen that (sometimes) does not only informs the OS about the closing screen but also executes "commands" via firmware (not controlled by the OS), some of which "commands" could be turning off the mousepad, etc.

Two workarounds that I can think off:

1) "Do nothing" when lid is closed: I don't know what desktop you are using, but most desktops give you the option of controlling which action to take when you close your lid; choose "do nothing" if possible (don't even blank the screen), `reboot` the computer and try again. If it works, then this could be the workaround itself, or you can start building up from this point (ex: try "blank the screen" next) until it stops working.

2) Disable the hardware switch: this one is the "dirty", last ditch approach. Disassemble your laptop, find the hardware switch that is triggered when closing the lid and "defeat" it. Sometimes only this option works.

Sorry if there's no better answer. I hope this helps.

**Edit**: some more things come to mind, which can be worth trying:

1) Make sure that you have an encompassing repository list `/etc/apt/sources.list` such as the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492718/after-upgrade-to-debian-jessie-random-mod-fcgid-errors/41494417#41494417), run `apt-get update`, install the package `firmware-linux`, reboot and see if the problem still exists.

2) Update your BIOS to the latest version, reboot and see if the problem persists.

3) Log in to your BIOS and change all settings of "energy saving" stuff to "off" (or enable maximum performance), reboot and check it again.

4) Find out your touchpad brand and model and search for issues related or drives available for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

**suggestion**

`modprobe -r i2c-hid; modprobe i2c-hid;` in http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=128952

**links**

`modprobe -r psmouse; modprobe psmouse` as in the question also in:

- https://matoski.com/article/debian-touchpad-not-working/ ;
- https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Touchpad_does_not_work_after_resuming_from_hibernate.2Fsuspend

similar questions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154997/mouse-network-turned-off-after-suspend (currently without answer)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/924074/ubuntu-touchpad-usb-mouse-click-event-not-working
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/862244/ubuntu-16-04-on-macbook-air-2009-wifi-suspend-and-touch-pad

**note**

a file in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` seems still (in 2021) to be a right place for sleep/suspend/... events, or in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ as shown in https://askubuntu.com/questions/671910/touchpad-not-working-after-suspending-laptop

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me:

**Step 1: List Loaded Touch-Related Kernel Modules**

To list loaded kernel modules related to "touch," run:

```bash
sudo lsmod | grep touch
```

**Description:** This command checks for loaded kernel modules with "touch" in their names, helping identify touch-related modules.

---

here's my output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Uux.png)

So in my case, here i have the hid_multitouch module which i unload using rmmod and reload using modprobe.

**Step 2: Unload `hid_multitouch` Module**

To unload the `hid_multitouch` module, execute:

```bash
sudo rmmod hid_multitouch
```

**Description:** This command removes the `hid_multitouch` kernel module, temporarily disabling its functionality. Useful for troubleshooting touch-related issues.

---

**Step 3: Manually Load `hid_multitouch` Module**

To manually load the `hid_multitouch` module, use:

```bash
sudo modprobe hid_multitouch
```

**Description:** This command loads the `hid_multitouch` kernel module, enabling touch input support. Useful when the module isn't loaded automatically during system startup.